# Ownership and criteria based sharing rule

Tags: sharing, sharing-rule, criteria-based-sharing

So I was going through some questions on sharing rules and found this one
Not sure what the concept should be.

**Can a single sharing rule be written to have both ownership and criteria based condtions in the rule and dynamically share the records with different public groups?
The options are

1. Yes, it is possible
2. Yes, but only possible with custom objects
3. No, it is not possible
4. Yes, it is possible only on Accounts**

The given answer is 1 but I can't understand why

When we go to sharing rules we can either choose ownership based rule or criteria based rule and then make the rules right?

Answer (score 0):

Remember that answers you find online are not necessarily correct.

Here is my logical argument:

I think this question may be meant as a trick because you have to choose a rule type for a sharing rule, either:

- Based on record owner
- Based on Criteria

but you can technically create a Criteria Based sharing rule and have one of your criteria as OwnerId = '005...'

I think this satisfies the following statement: 'write a sharing rule to have both ownership and criteria based conditions in the rule'

Coming back to this, I would still select **3 as the correct answer** since I don't believe you can **Dynamically** share the records with different public groups, you must select only one public group per sharing rule. (unless you have multiple sharing rules, but the question specifies a single sharing rule )

[image]

Comment: Exactly, even I think the answer should be 3 because there is a possibility of filtering through owner ID but still that's something that most people would prefer not to do.

Comment: If the dynamically sharing with public groups in a SINGLE RULE was not in the question I would say 1, but that is why I would go with 3 if this comes up on your cert exam! truth is you'll NEVER know if you got it right or wrong :) trust your do diligence!

Comment: okay! Will keep that in mind.